# How to pass value from HTML tag (other than <input> tag ) to view using Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to pass value from HTML tag (other than  tag ) to view  using Form ? In Django

I need to submit a form and pass the value holded in  tag to view

```
<div>
   <h3 class="media-title" id="user_name" name="user_name">
       {{ username}}
   </h3> 
   <button class="btn btn-small">
        <a href="{% url 'add_to_group' %}"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i> </a>
   </button>
</div>
```

How do i fetch the value `{{ username }}` in view `add_to_group` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add that argument to your url:

**urls.py**

```
path('<str:username>/', your_view, name='add_to_group'),
```

and in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'add_to_group' username %}"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i> </a>
```

#### Edit

As you mentioned in the comments, you should use this (if you want to pass the username to your url):

```
{% for us in user_list %}
  <div>
    <h3 class="media-title" id="user_name" name="user_name"> {{ us.name }} </h3>
    <button class="btn btn-small"><a href="{% url 'add_to_group' us.username %}"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i> </a></button>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks ...But it throws an error : Reverse for 'add_to_group' with arguments '(name: Administrator,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['auth_app\\/(?P<username>\\d+)/$']

Comment: @TonoKuriakose Show me the error so that I can help you with that.

Comment: Are you sure the `{{ username }}` is actually an string? I think you should use `<a href="{% url 'add_to_group' username.name %}"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i> </a>`

Comment: url(r'^<str:username>/', views.add_to_group, name="add_to_group"),

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /auth_app/load_user

Reverse for 'add_to_group' with arguments '(name: Administrator,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['auth_app\\/<str:username>/']

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth_app/load_user
Django Version:  2.1
Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:  

Reverse for 'add_to_group' with arguments '(name: Administrator,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['auth_app\\/<str:username>/']

Exception Location:  C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py

Comment: What is that `username`? I think it's a `dictionary` or model object rather than an string. Show me what is the value of `username`.

Comment: {% for us in user_list %}            <div>
   <h3 class="media-title" id="user_name" name="user_name">
       {{ us.name}}
   </h3> 
   <button class="btn btn-small">
        <a href="{% url 'add_to_group' %}"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i> </a>
   </button>
</div> {% endfor %}

Comment: path('<str:username>/', your_view, name='add_to_group'),                                          Here how can i pass url ?                                                                                               path('r'^add_to_group<str:username>/', your_view, name='add_to_group'),

Comment: Error during template rendering

In template D:\TONO\DJANGO_TASK\user_auth\templates\auth_app\other-user-listing.html, error at line 113
Reverse for 'add_to_group' with arguments '(name: Administrator,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['auth_app\\/<str:us.name>/']

Comment: Please show us the code where you are creating the `username` variable. As I already mentioned, it seems like the `username` is not holding as string value.

Comment: Username is a string value . Passed from Django view

Comment: It's working now, i used another url pattern ...............................................................url(r'^auth_app/add_to_group/(?P<username>(.*))/$', views.add_to_group, name='add_to_group'),